# MoveNext() breaks when calling an outside function

Tags: c#

Below is the code. New to C#. When there isn't a function call, the query string prints for each item, as expected and perfectly formatted. Unfortunately, when I call the ApiCall function, it runs once and stops, breaking the while loop - I never get to "doc-dispose".

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader($"Nebraska.json"))
{
    List<string> listOfParks = new List<string>();
    string? line;
    while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // breaks the string into 
        using JsonDocument documentSplitByLine = JsonDocument.Parse(line);
        // pulls the root element
        JsonElement root = documentSplitByLine.RootElement;
        // sets the element to allow for enumeration by line
        using(JsonElement.ArrayEnumerator parks = root.EnumerateArray())
            {
            while(parks.MoveNext())
            {
                string name = parks.Current.GetProperty("name").ToString();
                string local = parks.Current.GetProperty("location").ToString();
                string state = parks.Current.GetProperty("state").ToString();

                string thing = "";
                if(local.Contains(","))
                {
                    thing = local.Substring(0, local.IndexOf(','));
                }
                else if(local.Contains(" and "))
                {
                    thing = local.Substring(0, local.IndexOf(" and "));
                }
                else if(local.Contains("-"))
                {
                    thing = local.Substring(0, local.IndexOf("-"));
                }
                else if(local.Contains("("))
                {
                    thing = local.Substring(0, local.IndexOf("("));
                }
                else if(name.Contains("("))
                {
                    name = name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf("("));
                }
                else if(name.Contains(" -"))
                {
                    name = name.Substring(0, name.IndexOf(" -"));
                }
                else if(local.All(char.IsDigit))
                {
                    thing = local.Substring(0, local.First(char.IsDigit));
                }
                else if(local.Contains("/"))
                {
                    thing = local.Substring(0, local.IndexOf("/"));
                }
                else{
                    thing = local;
                }
                string query = name+"%20"+thing+"%20"+state;
                Console.WriteLine(query);
                // calls API with teh query string

     //ERROR HAPPENS WHEN ApiCall() is made. if this is commented out, function works as expected
                ApiCall(query);
                
            }
            Console.WriteLine("doc-dispose");
            documentSplitByLine.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

as requested, the ApiCall function. Maybe flexing my lack of depth of understanding in C#, but I didn't know that that call could affect the function calling it given it returns nothing

```
static void ApiCall (string query) 
{

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string baseAdd = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=";
    string tagAdd = "&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address%2Cname%2Crating%2Cgeometry&key=AIzaSyBr2e34qryWOxc5VrAO6xfod2SboB6mhhc";
    string finalQuery = baseAdd+query+tagAdd;

    Console.WriteLine("Calling web API...");
    // Below is the dog and pony show C# uses to say JSON.stringify()
    // because C# is dookie I guess
    var responseTask = client.GetAsync(finalQuery);
    responseTask.Wait();
    if(responseTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        var result = responseTask.Result;
        if(result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var messageTask = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            messageTask.Wait();
            JsonDocument documentSplitByLine = JsonDocument.Parse(messageTask.Result);
            JsonElement root = documentSplitByLine.RootElement;
            
            var parks = root.EnumerateObject();
            
            while(parks.MoveNext())
            {
                var park = parks.Current;
                var thing = park.Value[0];
                string name = "" +thing.GetProperty("name");
                string lat = "" +thing.GetProperty("geometry").GetProperty("location").GetProperty("lat");
                string lng = "" +thing.GetProperty("geometry").GetProperty("location").GetProperty("lng");
                string formatted_address = "" +thing.GetProperty("formatted_address");
                LatLng thisLatLng = new LatLng(float.Parse(lat), float.Parse(lng));
                StatePark thisPark = new StatePark(name, thisLatLng, formatted_address);
                thisPark.SayName();

            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("failed response");
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is perhaps moving to the next item? You are in a loop, after all. Can you provide a [mcve] and a better problem description? For example: what is `ApiCall`? Is it blocking and that's why it doesn't advance? If it is, perhaps the request is hanging, or perhaps you've misused async. Who knows? `ApiCall` is a black box that we can't examine. We also don't have any sample JSON.

Comment: You got it! Sorry about that, hopefully that's better info. Happy to add more if needed.

Comment: Try use .GetAwaiter().GetResult() instead of .wait() in the ApiCall method. Await is a better way if possible.

Comment: Chee I could kiss you on the mouth THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: BTW You shouldn't instantiate `HttpClient` every time you use it. Doing so instantiates an internal handler that essentially reserves a set of ports for its own use. These aren't quick to get disposed of, so with enough requests you can exhaust your system's supply of sockets, blocking further requests. The basic advice in Microsoft's documentation is to make `HttpClient` a static property or field and only instantiate it once. This ends up not respecting DNS changes, so that comes with its own set of issues, but it's better than your current approach.

Answer (score -1):

Issue was resolved by changing responseTask.Wait() to responseTask.GetAwaiter()